# Error integrating persistence in a Java application deployed in Web Logic 12c

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy a java 1.8 application on a Web Logic 12c server using persistence, at the time of deployment it marks me an error with persistence (`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes ()`), in my local it runs perfect, the problem is when trying to deploy the project in Linux development server.

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="bmm" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.bmn.merchant.entities.TransaccionEntity</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//0.0.0.0:0000/BNT00D"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.5/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <context-root>BanorteMerchantManager</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javassist.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mx.banorte</groupId>
    <artifactId>BanorteMerchantManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>BanorteMerchantManager</name>
    <description>Arma mensajes y envia a PRM Merchant</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.19.RELEASE</version>
        <!--<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version> -->
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.bmn.merchant.BanorteMerchantManagerApplication</start-class>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId> <artifactId>gson</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PRUEBA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The error that has been throwing me is the following: (I'm in a position where I could not change the server settings)

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index; but it does not exist. Its class, javax.persistence.Table, is available from the following locations:

    zip:/herramientas/servers/bea/domains/payworks_prm_dev/servers/prm_server_01/tmp/_WL_user/banortemerchantmanager/7ak6t9/war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/herramientas/servers/bea/wls1213/oracle_common/modules/javax.persistence_2.0.0.0_2-0.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/herramientas/servers/bea/wls1213/oracle_common/modules/javax.persistence_2.0.0.0_2-0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.Table
```

Comment: This requires a [mcve]. Your current code is too large.

Comment: You may have a conflict between 2 JPA libraries : One is provided by WebLogic (javax.persistence_2.0.0.0_2-0.jar) and the other is in your application's classpath (hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar). Remove the one in your application ; if its not possible update your weblogic.xml file to add jpa classes in prefred application packages.